# How do I await all spawned JoinHandles in a for loop

Tags: for-loop, rust, rust-tokio

I have the following code:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let db: Db = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));
    let block_res = get_block_addresses().await;

    match block_res {
        Ok(v) => {
            println!("Block downloaded, grabbing contracts");
            println!("Txs: {}", v.result.transactions.len());
            for obj in v.result.transactions {
                let db1 = db.clone();
                let db2 = db.clone();

                let to = obj.to.clone();
                let from = obj.from.clone();

                tokio::spawn(async move {
                    let resp = check_if_contract(to, db1).await;
                });

                tokio::spawn(async move {
                    let resp = check_if_contract(from, db2).await;
                });
            }



        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("error parsing header: {:?}", e);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it never awaits the result of the spawns. How can I properly await these `JoinHandle`s after the for loop has done it's thing? I wanted to avoid using an array of tasks and iterating over them. Since I had seen in Jon Gjengset's video that there exists something like a `NotifyHandle`, that stores tasks by id. But I have no clue how to use it, or if it even makes sense in this context. I'm new to rust and async programming so I hope my question made some sense.

Comment: You must either store a vector of joinhandles, or something like a [`WaitGroup`](https://docs.rs/awaitgroup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way at this point in time for a dynamic amount of tasks is to utilize [FuturesUnordered](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/stream/futures_unordered/struct.FuturesUnordered.html), which represents a collection of `Future`s where one can wait on the next `Future` to resolve.

In your case it would be something along:

```rust
let tasks = FuturesUnordered::new();

for obj in v.result.transactions {
    let db1 = db.clone();
    let db2 = db.clone();

    let to = obj.to.clone();
    let from = obj.from.clone();

    tasks.push(tokio::spawn(async move {
        check_if_contract(to, db1).await
    }));

    tasks.push(tokio::spawn(async move {
        check_if_contract(from, db2).await
    }));
}

while let Some(finished_task) = tasks.next().await {
    match finished_task {
        Err(e) => { /* e is a JoinError - the task has panicked */},
        Ok(result) => { /* result is the result of check_if_contract */ }
    }
}
```

If you need to identify the transaction in the final loop, return something which identifies the task from the functions you spawn - then it will be part of `result`.

Comment: What is the benefit over using a waitgroup?

Comment: What waitgroup? Link? There doesn't exist one in tokio.

Comment: If the futures are known at compile time, should I prefer `FuturesUnordered` over `join!()` ?

Comment: `result` is empty for me when I try to build using this method.